# .NET events cause uncontrollable memory usage

Tags: .net

Assume we have a single Windows form with a button called SimpleButton1. The following code results in an uncontrollable amount of memory usage. What am I doing incorrectly?

My understanding is that at every iteration of the for loop, GC cleans up any TestClass objects, and would take care of any associated events as well since there are no handlers on any of the events

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Dim test1 As New TestClass            
    Next
End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestClass
    Private Event TestEvent(ByVal sender As Object)
End Class
```

Note that I have tried implementing IDisposable and calling test1.Dispose() at the end of every iteration of the For loop, but I suspect I am not disposing the correct resources.

*ANSWERED: There was no problem in the code, and it was run as expected. Problem was that I was running it in debug mode, and the overhead that is created results in large memory usage. See discussion below.

Comment: Do you get memory problems with this _Exact_ code? Because I can't get it to make even a little bump in TaskManagers memory graph.

Comment: Yes -- this exact code. There are no other handlers subscribed to TestEvent or anything else creating instances of TestClass. Just a simple button that does Dim TestClass 1 million times.

Comment: Hmmm - not reproducable. Please retest.

Comment: I'm with Henk on this one - this *exact* code does almost nothing to memory usage, even when compiled in Debug and with breakpoints. Adding a "0" to the for loop does give it a slight bump, but it quickly goes back to normal.

Comment: @Henk and Philip: Just to clarify, are you guys looking at "Mem Usage" under the "Processes" tab for Windows Task Manager? If I press the button enough times, it eventually causes an out of memory exception for me. Do you think it could be something specific to my installation of .NET?

Comment: You didn't mention the "click enough times" before but I still can't see a problem.

Comment: One question - are you compiling under "release" or "debug", and are you debugging or running without when you do these tests?

Comment: I think I may have discovered the problem -- if I run the app under a Debug configuration or VS in debug mode, debug seems to be attaching itself to the events created without cleaning up and leaving a large overhead. Under a release configuration, this problem obviously does not occur.

Comment: @stacked - your comment hit just after my answer post.  The Debug configuration actually adds edit and continue tracking stuff to the code, which WILL eventually cause your example to run out of memory.  Runnnig under the vshost will also change things as I believe it alters the GC behavior to make sure things stick in memory whlie debugging for the watch windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running under Debug, VisualStudio will create extra code to help with edit and continue ( _EncList stuff), even if you are not under the debugger.

Make sure to compile and run in production compiled as "Release".  Yes, this makes it hard to debug memory issues when they behave differently, but it's not the hardest thing about tracking down memory issues.

Answer (score 5):

What you're not showing here and I suspect is the issue is that w/ in your TestClass, you have the event TestEvent and while you're probably adding handlers to TestEvent, you're probably not removing them. By not removing them, you're telling the GC not to collect either TestClass or the handler's class.

Comment: Re: James
I have not added any handlers to TestEvent, with the exception of possible handlers added at compilation or run time. There is nothing I would expect to need removal with the exception of default handlers created this way. Is there anything else in the .NET code I could show you specific to your comment, or is there any way to access handlers added at run time if that is actually the issue?

Comment: James, handlers to TestEvent are __outgoing__ references for the TestClass and will not block GC. Unless instances subscribe to each other.

Answer (score 5):

This code, as you have shown it, will not leak.  The garbage collector will eventually take care of the classes you created.

However, if you have an Observable class, and an Observer class, the Observer will call `Observable.Event += Observer.EventHandler;`  By doing this, the Observable now has a reference back to the Observer.  If you do not call `Observable.Event -= Observer.EventHandler`, then that reference stays around.

The problem with this happens when you think nobody has an reference to the Observer, but the Observable has a longer lifespan.  Although the Observable has a reference to the Observer, there is no code that knows to remove the reference, unless it clears out all of the handlers (`this.Event = null`).

This, in effect, is a memory leak!

There are several ways to get around this:

1. Call -= before you throw out the Observer.  Possibly in Dispose()
2. Use [Weak Events](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WeakEvents.aspx)
3. Consider a different eventing pattern, like the [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)

Comment: Thank you Brian. You say that "the garbage collector will eventually take care of the classes you created" -- when is "eventually"? If I compile this program and run it, Mem usage in task manager spirals out of control, and is never reclaimed. This eventually leads to an out of memory exception. This would seem to me that GC does not take care of any classes that I create.

Answer (score 3):

1. The GC does not spring into action on every iteration, it will wait until an opportune moment and sweep those objects en masse.
2. The TestEvent should not block collection by the GC, but if instances of the TestClass subscribe to an event on another object, then that will keep them alive. There is no automatic cleanup.
3. How do you ascertain "results in an uncontrollable amount of memory usage". Measuring memory usage is harder than it sounds. I hope this isn't based on TaskManager.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. About point 3:

It is based on Task Manager. This simple app I have wrote up is the result of my singling out the problem in a much larger app. The increase in memory usage eventually causes an out of memory exception.

Comment: @Stacked- in the larger one you probably have some of the issues others have described, particularly regarding the events.

Comment: RichardOD: If I comment out the "Private Event" line -- there is no memory usage problem. This is the same occurrence larger app. It is my understanding there are no handlers on my event, since if I comment out the event declaration it does not effect the app in any way except memory usage. Am I understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: stacked, there is no problem _with_ that event line either.